# Formatting Instant Search Hits section

Tags: javascript, html, algolia, instantsearch.js, instantsearch

I’m trying to show a hit section from a Algolia Instant Search as simple as a dropdown-item from bootstrap:

[image]

one result per line as a `<a>` link, without images.

But I only get this one:

[image]

**How can I get the dropdown-item (above) style , One item per line, without that borders and overlapping ?**

Code HTML for seachbox:

```
<form class="form-inline md-form my-0 mr-5 text-white ">
<i class=“fas fa-search white-text” aria-hidden=“true”></i>
<div id=“searchbox” class="text-white "></div>
<div id=“hits” class=“dropdown-menu text-white” ></div>
</form>
```

Code JS :

```
search.addWidget(
instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
container: “#searchbox”,
placeholder: “Search”,
showSubmit: false,
autofocus: false
})
);

  search.addWidget(
    instantsearch.widgets.hits({
      container: "#hits",
      templates: {
        empty: "None.",
        item: function(item) {
           return `<a class="dropdown-item" href="/question/${item.id_question}">${item.str_question}</a>`;
        }
      }  
    })
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see the inside of `<div id=“hits”></div>`

I am guessing there is a `ul` and `li`
you need to make those `display: block`
and a few more css properties
probably `white-space: pre;`

Can you provide the inside html for `<div id=“hits”></div>`? so we can provide a better answer.

Comment: There is nothing inside <div id=“hits”></div>. It exists only to mark where hits records should be placed, and are filled  dynamically by InstantSearch (https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/js/#add-the-search-ui-code).

Comment: it looks like InstantSearch shows how to customize the html & css of the hits items that are added
https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/getting-started/js/#customize-hits-and-add-a-final-touch

we would still need the html markup of the hits being added in order to properly help.

Comment: I just found a way to do that. I changed the Algolia.css "complete" file to Reset.css, the "minimum" file, as listed here: https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/building-search-ui/installation/js/#load-the-style . It works as I want.

Comment: Very nice, it sounds like you have figured everything out 